# Xamarin HybridWebView always opens in Browser with xamarin.iOS when using Appcues script

Tags: xamarin.ios

When i check in the script from Appcues then i see it trieds to embed an iframe to my body element.

I can see that adding an iframe with `<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>` in my website. That iOS apps opens to the native browser to google immediately. The same result when adding an Appcues script.

I can ignore the navigate to google url but if i do that for Appcues. Appcues doesn't get shown in my app. This works fine on Xamarin.Android

Comment: You want to open the webview in Browser(such as Safari)?

Comment: No, i want to stay in my HybridWebview app.